# PHP .htaccess redirect root to specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have website example: `http://example.com`

and on my local project I name the folder is `project1`. http://localhost/project1

Now when I copy the folder to public_html, I want `.htaccess` target it to the folder `project1`

So, when I open `http://example.com/` this will redirect to folder `project1`

How to do this on .htaccess?

Comment: If you don't have to access the file from out of the `project1` directory. You should change the `DocumentRoot` to the `public_html/project1` instead of using `.htaccess`. This will serve in the a secure way and web server do not need to read and process `.htaccess` every time.

Comment: @spicydog How can I change it?

Comment: Go to the apache configuration file, not sure which platform are you using. Check here for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/337874/change-apache-document-root-folder-to-secondary-hard-drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project1/index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

  ErrorDocument 404 /project1/?index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks , very good explanation, I was stuck in it for 2 days of now and this solution worked.